# How to disable OnClickListerners

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I am developing an app where the user has to match the image and corresponding name of it correctly.

My problem is when the user selects the image first and selects the wrong name it will display wrong answer and if he selects the answer it will be displayed correct answer.

The user should not have to re-select the image again

I have made the onClickListerner's null but it wont work some of my code is as follows,

```
    txt_tag[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_tag1);
    txt_tag[0].setOnClickListener(this);
    txt_tag[0].setTypeface(tf);

    txt_tag[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_tag2);
    txt_tag[1].setOnClickListener(this);
    txt_tag[1].setTypeface(tf);

    txt_tag[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_tag3);
    txt_tag[2].setOnClickListener(this);
    txt_tag[2].setTypeface(tf);

    txt_tag[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_tag4);
    txt_tag[3].setOnClickListener(this);
    txt_tag[3].setTypeface(tf);

    img[0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img1);
    img[0].setOnClickListener(this);

    img[1] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img2);
    img[1].setOnClickListener(this);

    img[2] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img3);
    img[2].setOnClickListener(this);

    img[3] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img4);
    img[3].setOnClickListener(this);

    btn_nxt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    btn_nxt.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and I have called an method inside that method where I have made all onClickListerner's null

```
txt_tag[0].setOnClickListener(null);
txt_tag[1].setOnClickListener(null);
txt_tag[2].setOnClickListener(null);
txt_tag[3].setOnClickListener(null);
img[0].setOnClickListener(null);
img[1].setOnClickListener(null);
img[2].setOnClickListener(null);
img[3].setOnClickListener(null);
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong or any modifications I can do to it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
       txt_tag[0].setClickable(false);
       txt_tag[1].setClickable(false);
       ..
       img[0].setClickable(false);
       img[1].setClickable(false);
       ..
```

Comment: you can also enable onClickListener again using true parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not that clear.. but if you want your image and text tag not clickable.. make them `android:clickable="false"` in xml or `setClickable(false);`

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would be checking that logic in a listener. So if the quiestion (if it's a quiz) is in the state "ANSWERED", don't react to event.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion, if you want you code up specific behaviour you can use the onClickListener callback to achieve what you want.

In the listener, check the state of the image; if it is already selected and you want to ignore the event then you just exit from your callback.

I think setting the onClickListener to null is the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, but I understand it as follows:

- You have a bunch of `ImageViews` and a bunch of `TextViews` and a Mapping between them.
- You want to be able to first select an `ImageView`, then a `TextView`. If they match, "correct answer" will be displayed somewhere, if not, "wrong answer" will be displayed
- If you click on a TextView before an ImageView is selected, nothing happens
- If you click on a Textview and another TextView is already selected, nothing happens

If that is correct, you can do this like this: You keep two variables

```
int selectedImage = -1;
int selectedText  = -1;
```

In your `OnClickListener` you update their values like this:

```
if (source instanceof ImageViews) {
  selectedImage = getArrayIndex(source); // I guess you already have a method to retrieve the index
  selectedText = -1; // reset textSelection
} else {
  if (selectedText < 0) {
    selectedText = getArrayIndex(source);
  }
}
updateAnswerTextView(); // here you check if the two selections (selectedText and selectedImage) match and display the corresponding string.
```

Instead, you could just iterate through the `TextView` array and call

```
setClickable(false);
```

on every element as soon as one is clicked. If a new image is selected, you will have to set them to clickable again.

EDIT: And I agree with Rob, you should not remove your `Listeners` to achieve this behaviour.